# AP Calculus AB multiple choice number 16

Tags: calculus

[image]

I know we're supposed to use the chaine rule then implicit differentiation. However, can  someone show me a step by step explaination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\dfrac{d}{dx}(\sin(xy))=\dfrac{d}{d(xy)}(\sin(xy))\times\dfrac{d}{dx}(xy)=1\\
\implies \cos(xy)\left(y+x\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)=1\\
\implies \dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{1-y\cos(xy)}{x\cos(xy)}$$

Comment: I was wondering why in the first line, why we use d/dx, then change to dy/dx on the next line.

Comment: @chrissykwon Product rule.

Comment: So the d/dx just goes nowhere?

Comment: @chrissykwon $$\dfrac{d}{dx}(xy)=\dfrac{dx}{dx}y+x\dfrac{dy}{dx}$$

Comment: I understand that, but doesnt d/dx mean that we are taking the derivative for X?

Comment: @chrissykwon I don't understand what question you are trying to ask in the comments. Please do elaborate.

Comment: doesn't  d/dx  mean that we are taking the derivative for x ?

Comment: To rephrase, what does d/dx exactly mean?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14250/discussion-between-sanath-devalapurkar-and-chrissy-kwon)

Comment: I am on the chat.